# How to implement multiple-level filters in an extensible manner?

Tags: algorithm, filter

Should make it extensible.

When I say make it extensible,I mean that the detail of filter options can be added later on with ease.

By design,it's better that parsing and rendering are independant.(?)

During parsing,need to show the next level filter options if neccesary.

I mean it should be within filtering length of each filter label by "if neccesary".

How to make the detail of filtering options extensible when the detail of options is no neccesary?

For performance issue,should make all related fields in the same table.

For a live demo of the filters,see [here](http://losangeles.kijiji.com/f-Classifieds-W0QQAdTypeZ2QQSortZ4QQminPriceZ1Q2c000).

Comment: What programming language or environment are you talking about here?

Comment: The server side language is PHP.But it's not important.It's the algorithm that's the key.

Comment: Filtering what? Coffee grounds? Text? you seem to think it's obvious what you are doing here, and maybe someone will turn up who agrees with you.

Comment: I've provided a live link there.You can check it out if still not clear what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)?

Comment: Buddy,I need a more specific solution now.Principles help,but not much.

Comment: OK - here are several examples of implementing the Decorator pattern in PHP: http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/decorator_pattern

Comment: I've known about this pattern and used it several times.But this time,it seems hard to help.